# How to silence Xcode 11.4 warnings about MobileCoreServices and AssetsLibrary?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode11.4

After upgrading to **Xcode 11.4 beta** I've got those warnings from `Pods` subproject (specifically, from `YYImage` and `Branch` targets):

> Target Integrity: MobileCoreServices has been renamed. Use CoreServices instead.
>
> Target Integrity: AssetsLibrary is deprecated. Consider migrating to Photos instead.

I have `inhibit_all_warnings!` in my `Podfile`, but it has no effect on those.

Is there a way to silence those warnings until the creators of those pods will fix them?

Comment: Change podspec's dependencies section, change `MobileCoreServices` to `CoreServices`

Comment: This can help if you're willing to fork pod's repository, but AFAIK, there is no way to patch *Podspec* with Cocoa Pods install hooks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue stemming from a 3rd party library that isn't coming in as a Pod.  I really need a way to just be able to turn off that specific warning, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I noticed that manually removing those two frameworks from `Pods/Frameworks/iOS` project navigator group resolves those warnings. Since both frameworks embedded into iOS itself (not app bundle) removing them doesn't have any effect at runtime. Here is how to do it automatically in `Podfile` post-install hook:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.frameworks_group["iOS"]["MobileCoreServices.framework"].remove_from_project
    installer.pods_project.frameworks_group["iOS"]["AssetsLibrary.framework"].remove_from_project
end
```

If this leaves a hanging `(null)` reference, you can do something like:

```
post_install do |installer|
    framework = installer.pods_project.frameworks_group["iOS"]["MobileCoreServices.framework"]
    framework.referrers.each do |ref|
        if ref.isa == "PBXBuildFile"
            ref.remove_from_project
        end
    end
    framework.remove_from_project
end
```

Answer (score 4):

For mute this warning:

1. Open Pod target's Build Settings
2. Select Build Options
3. Add framework (e.g. AssetsLibrary) to `Validate Workspace - Ignored Frameworks`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change platform :ios, '13.0' to
platform :ios, '11.0' in iOS/Podfile

worked like a charm for me!

Comment: Thanks for tuning in, but changing your deployment target just to silence a warning is not a very good idea.